# SVG graph with variable width

Tags: graph, svg

[image: Example of Desired Result]

I am trying to create an SVG graph with a fixed width to the left for the x axis labels and then a variable width to fill the remaining space for the actual graph results. The image below shows what I am trying to achieve. Thus far I have been unable to work out how to create the fixed width and variable width area.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would nest a couple of SVG elements inside your main like so:

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500px" height="500px" >

    <svg width="100">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    </svg>

    <svg x="100" >
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" opacity="0.5"/>
    </svg>

</svg>
```

NOTE I made the blue SVG element translucent so you can see that none of the red SVG was behind it.

I would also recommend using `viewBox` to give you more control over your drawing...

EDIT:

OK then I need to ask you a question about aspect ratios.  If you take a square (width = height) and chop off a fixed portion from **ONE** side you no longer have a square and you have to think about what that means to your graph.

I believe this SVG will demonstrate more or less what you want:

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
width="600px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 1200 1000">

<svg width="200">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>

<svg x="200" width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" opacity="0.5"/>
    <rect x="80%" y="10%" width="10%" height="50%" fill="green"/>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="70" height="40" fill="gray"/>
</svg>
```

NOTE the aspect ratio (AR) of the outermost `SVG`'s dimensions **MUST** match the outermost `viewBox`'s AR but can have different values.  Likewise for the second inner `SVG`, but now you are dealing with a slice of the total that is a true square and not a rectangle.  You can vary the width and height of the outer most `SVG` and so long as you maintain the same AR all the code on the inside will not have to change - it will all scale automajically :)

Also note the different scales in use and the different value types I used for co-ordinates.  Because my second inner `SVG`'s `viewBox` set the user co-ordinates to 100 X 100, 10% and 10 amount to the same thing...

You could also set the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` or some other value to achieve different effects but for a graph I kinda think lining things up is important so I wouldn't.

One final note - you could (and in your case should) omit the `viewBox` on the inner `SVG`.  That way the scale is consistent on all parts of your graph.  I was just showing off the power of `viewBox` :)

It just occurred to me that you may prefer a rectangle to a square so here is a code sample for that:

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
width="800px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 1600 800" >

<svg width="200">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>

<svg x="200" width="1400" height="800" viewBox="0 0 175 100" >
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" opacity="0.5"/>
    <rect x="80%" y="10%" width="10%" height="50%" fill="green"/>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="70" height="40" fill="gray"/>
</svg>
```

NOTE the width of the inner `SVG` is set to 175 so that the aspect ratio of 1400/800 is maintained.

Comment: Thanks, this works to an extent however any content within the second nested SVG element such as the blue rect with a width of 100% has is the width of the main SVG element however I need it to only be 100% of the nested element. Is this possible at all?